# The power of the family of all limited sets of lattice points

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of points on plane is limited, if it is contained in a circle.
Lattice points are the points with integer coordinates. What is the power of the family of all
limited sets of lattice points?

Comment: what do you mean by "power"

Comment: @K.Ghosh Power of the family = number of elements in it or cardinal number representing that

Comment: @ArthurFischer no, just that a such circle exist, which contain all points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bounded* is the usual English term for what you have called *limited*.

The set of lattice points is countably infinite: its cardinality is $\omega$ (or $\aleph_0$, if you prefer). Every bounded set of lattice points is finite. A countably infinite set has countably infinitely many finite subsets, so there are at most $\omega$ bounded sets of lattice points. On the other hand, there are clearly infinitely many such sets, so there are precisely $\omega$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that within a particular circle there can only be finitely many lattice points.

Furthermore there is a countable number of lattice points, since $\mathbb{|Z|=|N|=|N\times N|=|Z\times Z|}=\aleph_0$.

Lastly, we know that if $A$ is countable then $\{B\subseteq A\mid B\text{ finite}\}$ is also countable.

Combine these and we have that the set of all sets of bounded lattice points is a subset of a countably infinite set, since it is an infinite set itself it has to have size $\aleph_0$.